# Why is vbCrLf being inserted in my string as a literal, rather than a new line?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

I have a string:

```
Dim str = "version=""1.0"" & VbCrLf & TIME=10:12:23"
```

If I run `MsgBox(str)`, it returns

> version="1.0" & VbCrLf & TIME=10:12:23

I want it to be:

> version="1.0"
>   TIME=10:12:23

How to do that (return two lines)?

Comment: It is likely unrelated to your problem here, but you really should declare your variables with explicit types. So instead of `Dim str`, use `Dim str As String = "..."`

Answer (score 8):

It seems that you are missing closing " after version definition, and Vb includes all text you  typed into string. Thing is that in order to insert quotation mark into string you need to write them twice: "". And in the end of string " becomes """, which is "" - a single quotation symbol and " symbol which closes the string.

Hence, maybe

```
Dim str = "version=""1.0""" & VbCrLf & "TIME=10:12:23"
```

would help?

**Update**: test from linqpad:

```
Dim str = "version=""1.0""" & Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.VbCrLf & "TIME=10:12:23"
Microsoft.VisualBasic.MsgBox(str)
```

Result is:

[image]

**Update 2**. After some discussion in comments it seems that the question is "how to evaluate a piece of code dynamically in Vb.Net / C#". So the question is much broader, it is about using compiler as service.

In order to evaluate an expression correctly, the most advanced way (AFAIK) is to use Roslyn. As I wrote in here ([Evaluating a mathematical expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20234347/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression/20234471#20234471)) one could do something like that (it is C# but it can be easily translated into Vb.Net):

```
using Roslyn.Scripting.CSharp;

namespace RoslynScriptingDemo {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)        {
            var engine = new ScriptEngine();
            engine.Execute(@"System.Console.WriteLine((450*5)+((3.14*7)/50)*100);");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declaration `Dim str = "version=""1.0"" & VbCrLf & TIME=10:12:23"` makes the string contain this: `version="1.0" & VbCrLf & TIME=10:12:23`. Declaration I proposed (`Dim str = "version=""1.0""" & VbCrLf & "TIME=10:12:23"`) makes the string contain this: `version="1.0" {newline}
TIME=10:12:23`. And this is exactly what you asked for. Have you tried my version of code?

Comment: Okay I simplify my question: Dim str ="version=1.0 & VbCrLf & TIME=10:12:23". How to tell VB that there is a carriagereturnlinefeed? I know that I can split the string by "Vbcrlf" but that's not the point.

Comment: Ok. I am still unsure what you need, but you could then try `str = str.Replace("& VbCrLf &", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.VbCrLf)`

Comment: The last comment you posted is nonsense, but no matter, you've already got the correct answer. He's missing a quotation mark. The syntax highlighting should have made that very clear. No idea why he disagreed with you. Here's a +1.

Comment: @CodyGray It now seems to me he really wants to tranform an ugly string with `& VbCrLf &` inside it into a string with carriage return... Thanks for +1 ))

Comment: I really don't like when people get rude after you help them.  @user3625117, you are missing the third and final quote at the end of `"version=""1.0"""`  You need to add that as Rustam said in order to get the results you want.  And please don't be rude.  You came to us for help.  Please show some respect.

Comment: @MauriceReeves I guess the guy might be not very good in English, since it's hard for him to explain what he wants to achieve. As I wrote in my previous comment,  he might really want to  tranform an ugly string with `& VbCrLf &` inside it into a string with carriage return. So I proposed him to use `Replace` for this case, but unfortunately he didn't return with any further comments )

Comment: well it's hard to explain... what I mean is if I have a string Dim str="1+2", I want msgbox(str) to return "3" (not "1+2"), something like that.. there is nothing to do with the quote "

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to create such a string is using `String.Format`

```
 Dim msg As String = 
    String.Format("version="{0}{1}{0} {2} Time = {3}", 
                  Chr(34), varVersion, Environment.NewLine, varTime)
```

Even if you are using literals (`"1.0"`) instead of variables (`varVersion`) the code is more readable.

`version = "1.0"
 Time = 07:24`

Using quotes makes everything more complicated, so dont do that.  I usually use [brackets] in place of them:

```
 Dim msg As String = 
    String.Format("version="[{0}] {2} Time = [{3}]", 
                  varVersion, Environment.NewLine, varTime)
```

`version = [1.0]
 Time = [07:24]`

Comment: this is really going too far.. and the moderator has changed my question.. what I really want is to eval what's inside the string. For example if I have a string Dim str as string = "1+2"  I want msgbox(str) to return "3" not "1+2", something like that..

Comment: a) thankfully, VB wont evaluate strings.  it is not part of NET for security reasons.  b) if the Edit does not reflect your question accurately, you can edit your own question to further clarify.  I would append an **Edit** section so that all these answers dont look like they are all from left field.

Answer (score 0):

For a quote, you need """" (four quotes).
Hence:

```
Dim s As String = "version=" & """" & "1.0" & """" & vbCrLf & "TIME=10:12:23"
MsgBox(s)
```

OR:

```
Dim q as Char = """"
Dim s() As String = "version=" & q & "1.0" & q & vbCrLf & "TIME=10:12:23"
MsgBox(s)
```

Here's why:
One quote opens or closes a string literal.
Two quotes indicate an empty string.
Three quotes is therefore an empty string plus an orphaned string delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing a double quote after the 1.0:

`Dim str = "version=""1.0""" & vbCrLf & "TIME=10:12:23"`

Answer (score 0):

Or Use This for shorter your code...

Dim str As String = "version=" & Chr(34) & "1.0" & Chr(34) & vbCrLf & "TIME=10:12:23"

Chr(34) is equivalent to Double Quote "

Answer (score -2):

See [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim Text As String = "version=""1.0"" & vbCrLf & TIME=10:12:23"
MsgBox(Text.Replace(" & vbCrLf & ", vbCrLf))
```

Comment: vbCrLf is already in the whole string. It is only one string, no concatenation.

Comment: What is the point of `String.Join` here? This code isn't even correct, `String.Join` expects the second parameter to be an array. `str` is not an array.